# Infinite loading screen on google play services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-play-services

Ive set up my google cloud platform credentials because i want my app to use cloud saves. Everything works perfect when testing, whenever i build from unity to my phone everything works fine.
But then i uploaded my app to google play as closed testing, changed the sha1 keys on oauth on google clouds platform to the App signing key certificate and only the emails that are added as test users on the OAuth consent screen get and infinite loading. All other accounts work fine and are able to connect to google services just fine. Ive also change the key on oauth to Upload key certificate and the problem persists.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: In the **IAM & Admin** component, could you use **Policy Troubleshooter** to see the access of your test users? You can follow the [Troubleshooting access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-access) documentation and follow the video.
Also, if posible, share the API call output.